Бот вроде бы должен превращать mp4 в gif но так как это происходит долго то дискорд ругается
Бот вроде бы должен превращать mp4 в gif но так как это происходит долго то дискорд ругается

Ошибка в работе бота discord.gateway: Shard ID None heartbeat blocked for more than seconds.

после чего

discord.client:Ignoringexception in on_message

import discord 
from discord.ext import commands
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip

intents = discord.Intents.default() # Подключаем "Разрешения"
intents.message_content = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>', intents=intents)
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Suckass: bot is connected to Discord")

@bot.event
async def on_message(ctx):
    if ctx.attachments:
        attachment = ctx.attachments[0]
        if attachment.filename.endswith('.mp4'):
            try:
                await attachment.save("temp.mp4")  # Сохраняем вложение временно

                video_clip = VideoFileClip("temp.mp4")
                gif_name = "converted.gif"
                video_clip.write_gif(gif_name)

                await ctx.send(file=discord.File(gif_name))

            except Exception as e:
                await ctx.send(f"Произошла ошибка: {e}")
            finally:
                # Удаляем временный файл
                import os
                os.remove("temp.mp4")
        else:
            await ctx.send("Пожалуйста, прикрепите файл в формате MP4.")
    else:
        await ctx.send("Вложение не найдено.")

bot.run('token')

полное сообщение об ошибке (не уверен что оно необходимо)
[2024-10-01 13:34:03] [WARNING ] discord.gateway: Shard ID None heartbeat blocked for more than 10 seconds.
Loop thread traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Denis\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\gif bot", line 38, in <module>
    bot.run('token')
  File "C:\Users\Denis\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 869, in run
    asyncio.run(runner())
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 190, in run
    return runner.run(main)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 641, in run_until_complete
    self.run_forever()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 321, in run_forever
    super().run_forever()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 608, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1936, in _run_once
    handle._run()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\asyncio\events.py", line 84, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
  File "C:\Users\Denis\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 449, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Denis\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\gif bot", line 23, in on_message
    video_clip.write_gif(gif_name)
  File "<decorator-gen-60>", line 2, in write_gif
  File "C:\Users\Denis\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\moviepy\decorators.py", line 54, in requires_duration
    return f(clip, *a, **k)
  File "<decorator-gen-59>", line 2, in write_gif
  File "C:\Users\Denis\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\moviepy\decorators.py", line 22, in convert_masks_to_RGB
    return f(clip, *a, **k)
  File "C:\Users\Denis\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\moviepy\video\VideoClip.py", line 432, in write_gif
    write_gif_with_image_io(self, filename, fps=fps, opt=opt, loop=loop,
  File "C:\Users\Denis\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\imageio\v2.py", line 200, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\Denis\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\imageio\v2.py", line 190, in close
    self.instance.close()
  File "C:\Users\Denis\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\imageio\plugins\pillow.py", line 144, in close
    self._flush_writer()
  File "C:\Users\Denis\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\imageio\plugins\pillow.py", line 485, in _flush_writer
    primary_image.save(self._request.get_file(), **self.save_args)
  File "C:\Users\Denis\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2439, in save
    save_handler(self, fp, filename)
  File "C:\Users\Denis\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\PIL\GifImagePlugin.py", line 704, in _save_all
    _save(im, fp, filename, save_all=True)
  File "C:\Users\Denis\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\PIL\GifImagePlugin.py", line 715, in _save
    if not save_all or not _write_multiple_frames(im, fp, palette):
  File "C:\Users\Denis\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\PIL\GifImagePlugin.py", line 602, in _write_multiple_frames
    im_frame = _normalize_mode(im_frame.copy())
  File "C:\Users\Denis\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\PIL\GifImagePlugin.py", line 492, in _normalize_mode
    im = im.convert("P", palette=Image.Palette.ADAPTIVE)
  File "C:\Users\Denis\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1029, in convert
    im = self.im.quantize(colors)

[2024-10-01 13:34:13] [WARNING ] discord.gateway: Shard ID None heartbeat blocked for more than 20 seconds.
Loop thread traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Denis\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\gif bot", line 38, in <module>
    bot.run('token')
  File "C:\Users\Denis\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 869, in run
    asyncio.run(runner())
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 190, in run
    return runner.run(main)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 641, in run_until_complete
    self.run_forever()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 321, in run_forever
    super().run_forever()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 608, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1936, in _run_once
    handle._run()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\asyncio\events.py", line 84, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
  File "C:\Users\Denis\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 449, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Denis\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\gif bot", line 23, in on_message
    video_clip.write_gif(gif_name)
  File "<decorator-gen-60>", line 2, in write_gif
  File "C:\Users\Denis\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\moviepy\decorators.py", line 54, in requires_duration
    return f(clip, *a, **k)
  File "<decorator-gen-59>", line 2, in write_gif
  File "C:\Users\Denis\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\moviepy\decorators.py", line 22, in convert_masks_to_RGB
    return f(clip, *a, **k)
  File "C:\Users\Denis\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\moviepy\video\VideoClip.py", line 432, in write_gif
    write_gif_with_image_io(self, filename, fps=fps, opt=opt, loop=loop,
  File "C:\Users\Denis\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\imageio\v2.py", line 200, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\Denis\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\imageio\v2.py", line 190, in close
    self.instance.close()
  File "C:\Users\Denis\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\imageio\plugins\pillow.py", line 144, in close
    self._flush_writer()
  File "C:\Users\Denis\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\imageio\plugins\pillow.py", line 485, in _flush_writer
    primary_image.save(self._request.get_file(), **self.save_args)
  File "C:\Users\Denis\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2439, in save
    save_handler(self, fp, filename)
  File "C:\Users\Denis\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\PIL\GifImagePlugin.py", line 704, in _save_all
    _save(im, fp, filename, save_all=True)
  File "C:\Users\Denis\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\PIL\GifImagePlugin.py", line 715, in _save
    if not save_all or not _write_multiple_frames(im, fp, palette):
  File "C:\Users\Denis\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\PIL\GifImagePlugin.py", line 602, in _write_multiple_frames
    im_frame = _normalize_mode(im_frame.copy())
  File "C:\Users\Denis\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\PIL\GifImagePlugin.py", line 492, in _normalize_mode
    im = im.convert("P", palette=Image.Palette.ADAPTIVE)
  File "C:\Users\Denis\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1029, in convert
    im = self.im.quantize(colors)

[2024-10-01 13:34:24] [WARNING ] discord.gateway: Shard ID None heartbeat blocked for more than 30 seconds.
Loop thread traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Denis\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\gif bot", line 38, in <module>
    bot.run('token')
  File "C:\Users\Denis\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 869, in run
    asyncio.run(runner())
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 190, in run
    return runner.run(main)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 641, in run_until_complete
    self.run_forever()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 321, in run_forever
    super().run_forever()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 608, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1936, in _run_once
    handle._run()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\asyncio\events.py", line 84, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
  File "C:\Users\Denis\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 449, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Denis\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\gif bot", line 23, in on_message
    video_clip.write_gif(gif_name)
  File "<decorator-gen-60>", line 2, in write_gif
  File "C:\Users\Denis\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\moviepy\decorators.py", line 54, in requires_duration
    return f(clip, *a, **k)
  File "<decorator-gen-59>", line 2, in write_gif
  File "C:\Users\Denis\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\moviepy\decorators.py", line 22, in convert_masks_to_RGB
    return f(clip, *a, **k)
  File "C:\Users\Denis\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\moviepy\video\VideoClip.py", line 432, in write_gif
    write_gif_with_image_io(self, filename, fps=fps, opt=opt, loop=loop,
  File "C:\Users\Denis\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\imageio\v2.py", line 200, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\Denis\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\imageio\v2.py", line 190, in close
    self.instance.close()
  File "C:\Users\Denis\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\imageio\plugins\pillow.py", line 144, in close
    self._flush_writer()
  File "C:\Users\Denis\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\imageio\plugins\pillow.py", line 485, in _flush_writer
    primary_image.save(self._request.get_file(), **self.save_args)
  File "C:\Users\Denis\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2439, in save
    save_handler(self, fp, filename)
  File "C:\Users\Denis\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\PIL\GifImagePlugin.py", line 704, in _save_all
    _save(im, fp, filename, save_all=True)
  File "C:\Users\Denis\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\PIL\GifImagePlugin.py", line 715, in _save
    if not save_all or not _write_multiple_frames(im, fp, palette):
  File "C:\Users\Denis\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\PIL\GifImagePlugin.py", line 602, in _write_multiple_frames
    im_frame = _normalize_mode(im_frame.copy())
  File "C:\Users\Denis\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\PIL\GifImagePlugin.py", line 492, in _normalize_mode
    im = im.convert("P", palette=Image.Palette.ADAPTIVE)
  File "C:\Users\Denis\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1029, in convert
    im = self.im.quantize(colors)

[2024-10-01 13:34:32] [ERROR   ] discord.client: Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Denis\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\gif bot", line 25, in on_message
    await ctx.send(file=discord.File(gif_name))
          ^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'send'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Denis\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\gif bot", line 28, in on_message
    await ctx.send(f"Произошла ошибка: {e}")
          ^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'send'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Denis\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 449, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Denis\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\gif bot", line 32, in on_message
    os.remove("temp.mp4")
PermissionError: [WinError 32] Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу, так как этот файл занят другим процессом: 'temp.mp4'
[2024-10-01 13:34:32] [ERROR   ] discord.client: Attempting a reconnect in 0.08s
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Denis\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 667, in connect
    await self.ws.poll_event()
  File "C:\Users\Denis\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\discord\gateway.py", line 648, in poll_event
    raise ConnectionClosed(self.socket, shard_id=self.shard_id, code=code) from None
discord.errors.ConnectionClosed: Shard ID None WebSocket closed with 1000
[2024-10-01 13:34:33] [INFO    ] discord.gateway: Shard ID None has successfully RESUMED session 85c456891b4873db9ea4f6d2bcfe9977.


У вас там сначала предупреждения, что вы надолго поток блокируете. Это можно вылечить асинхронностью вызова: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65882269/8324991  А дальше у вас ошибки. По первой ошибке попробуйте ctx.channel.send вместо ctx.send. А потом у вас ругается на os.remove("temp.mp4"), потому что файл кем-то занят.
